# Split Up Big Polygon Into Smaller Ones By Condition

Tags: postgis, polygon, leaflet, algorithm, splitting

I have some big Polygon. Within it collection of leaflet layers (points). Every point have some numeric property. What I want is split up big Polygon into smaller ones. 
Every smaller polygon should contain points with ~equal (+-200 ok) sum of points properties. On the left side of my example page I added image of desirable result.
[Here is my simplified example](https://codepen.io/ckpunmep/pen/POJLNN) with sufficient code and comments.

1. So my first step is find some start point within big Polygon. It's should be point near Polygon edge - the northernmost point for example.

   `var nothernmostPoint= 0;
   var nothernmostLayer= 0;
   L.geoJSON(features, {
       pointToLayer: function (feature) {
           return L.circleMarker(feature.geometry.coordinates.reverse(), defaultPointStyle);
       },
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           if (feature.geometry.coordinates[0] > nothernmostPoint) {
               nothernmostPoint = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
               nothernmostLayer = feature;
           }
       }
   }).addTo(map);`

---

2. Second step is to find next nearest point(s) to my start point.

   `var geoJ = L.GeometryUtil.nClosestLayers(map, features, 
   nothernmostLayer.geometry.coordinates, 5);`

---

3. Then sum up their properties. If sum is smaller than needed I go to step 2 and repeat, if sum is satisfy condition then I draw polygon with chosen points inside it and find nearest point to my last point and repeat search for points for the next smaller polygon.

---

My current difficulty is to find nearest point(s) to my start point. For that purpose I use **GeometryUtil Leaflet plugin**. Red dots are points that **GeometryUtil** found as nearest to my start point (the green one). It's certainly not what I was expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Maybe I should use different algorithm and/or tool for that task.

If it may help - all that data I store in **PostgreSQL** with **PostGIS** extension. Maybe this can be done on database level.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `L.GeometryUtil.nClosestLayers` method in this case always returns the first five elements from `features` array (tested).

Since I could not quickly find the reason for this behaviour, here is one possible solution for finding first five closest points:

```
var i, j;
var distance;
var nearestPoint = [];

for (i = 0; (i < features.length); i++) {
  distance = map.distance(features[i].geometry.coordinates, nothernmostLayer.geometry.coordinates);
  if (distance == 0) continue;
  if (nearestPoint.length == 0) {
    nearestPoint[0] = [i, distance];
    }
  else {
    for (j = 0; (j < nearestPoint.length); j++) {
      if (distance < nearestPoint[j][1]) {
        nearestPoint.splice(j, 0, [i, distance]);
        if (nearestPoint.length > 5) {
          nearestPoint.splice(5, 1);
        };
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the end array `nearestPoint` contains five pairs `[iPoint, dist]`, where `iPoint` is index of the point in `features` array in `dist` is distance of the point.